# After getting NAT working on Ubuntu 16.04, ssh connections into the router won't work

Tags: iptables

I just got a new install from my ISP for a project I'm working on in which I am using my own router using PPPoE to connect to the ISP. My router (Ubuntu 16.04) has two Ethernet adapters - one running PPPoE to connect to the ISP and the other feeding my local LAN as 192.168.0.0. The adapter on that LAN is 192.168.0.1.

I managed to get PPPoE up and running and got DHCP working and DNS working. All was well with the world at that point. At that point I could ssh into this box remotely using the static IP my ISP gave me.

The final step was to get NAT working. As soon as I got NAT up and running, I could no longer ssh in from the internet using my static IP. If I flush my iptables, then things are fine (but I lose NAT of course). When I reload the tables, I lose ssh.

With NAT running, everything else is fine - machines behind the router can access remote websites and can ssh to remote sites. The only thing that breaks is my ability to ssh into my router remotely.

Now, I realize that I probably don't want to be able to ssh in remotely in the long term, but my question is how to fix this, not how to "not do it". First I want to understand what's happening, and second, in the short term while I'm playing and experimenting, I want to be able to ssh into this router from the internet.

I understand the basic principles behind NAT and what is does, but being new to NAT, I don't really understand how the tables make it do what needs to be done. So I'm also hoping someone can help me with that too - there's only a few flavors of lines in there that need explaining. I'm hoping someone can at least have a look at my iptables and spot what it is that I need to add or delete to fix the problem, and it would be nice if they could help me understand why.

Here's what I get from iptables-save:

```
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [437:32936]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1025:121653]
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i ppp0 -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o enp1s0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -o ppp0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i ppp0 -o enp1s0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
COMMIT


*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [664:132498]
:INPUT ACCEPT [227:18335]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [410:31400]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [7:522]
-A POSTROUTING -o ppp0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [53197:28014137]
:INPUT ACCEPT [1215:191342]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [51916:27803280]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1027:122421]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [52950:27926212]
COMMIT
```

What is with the [123456:987654] notation?

So that's the whole story. Thanks in advance.

-gt-

Comment: Pretty simple - you forgot to ACCEPT the port 22 traffic inbound over ppp0 - so everything hits the default REJECT rule.  See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the notation, from the manpages: `<chain-name> <chain-policy> [<packet-counter>:<byte-counter>]` is the spec - first number is the number of packets that've been handled per the default chain policy, and the second is the total number of bytes of all the packets.

---

Regarding your unable to access SSH problem, that's because you didn't specify ACCEPT rules for the SSH port and service from the Outside, and have a default REJECT rule for all NEW traffic.

You need an ALLOW rule on inbound SSH via PPPoE - `-A INPUT -i ppp0 -m state --state NEW -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT` before your REJECT rule, to specify that "For NEW TCP connections on port 22 coming into the system via `ppp0` interface, permit that connection.

Comment: Thanks so much, Thomas, for the fix and the explanations. I really did try to solve this on my own, but I found the sources I consulted confusing and incomplete. Can you recommend a really straightforward primer on how iptables works so I can learn this stuff properly? Thanks!

Comment: @GeorgeTownsend Most of the knowledge is from understanding how firewalls work and in what order things behave.  There's no comprehensive guide that explains this process for `iptables` and the only way to really learn how things behave is to follow examples on how to properly configure `iptables` from scratch.  I have several answers to other questions on how to get a basic-functionality `iptables` setup, you might want to experiment with those in LXD containers or VMs so as not to break your main system behavior.

Comment: @GeorgeTownsend Also, if my answer helped you fix the issue (and restored your access to things) please accept this answer.  I can be found in the chat on a regular basis if you need assistance more with networking, or you can reach out to me directly (see my Launchpad profile for email contact mechanisms - https://launchpad.net/~teward)